# NSSortDescriptor - Sort descriptor based on another array

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I hava a core data application. And I want to fetch one kind of object, `User`. `User` have the property `userId`.

I have another array with `userId`s, `[1, 4, 3, 5]`. And I would like to create a `NSSortDescriptor` that sorts my `User`objects based on the order of the `userId`s in the array.

Is that possible, and how should I do that?

**Update**

I have now tried the following.

1. I added a transformable property to my User object, where I store the user ids array.
2. I have tried the following sort descriptor:

   ```
   sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"userId" ascending:YES     comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
       NSUInteger idx1 = [self.user.followingIds indexOfObject:[obj1 valueForKey:@"userId"]];
       NSUInteger idx2 = [self.user.followingIds indexOfObject:[obj2 valueForKey:@"userId"]];
       return idx1 - idx2;
   }];
   ```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This  is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.   [<__NSCFNumber 0xa337400> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant  for the key userId. with userInfo {
    NSTargetObjectUserInfoKey = 2502;
    NSUnknownUserInfoKey = userId;
}
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:    '[<__NSCFNumber 0xa337400> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-   compliant for the key userId.'
```

**Update 2**

Would also like to add a relationship `Followers` between `User` objects. Any ideas how that relationship should look? See attached image. Is that correct?

[image]

Comment: are you storing userId on your DB.If this then use amit answer to accomplish it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can not be done with a sort descriptor, you have to apply a custom comparator function after fetching the results:

```
NSArray *userIds = ...; // e.g. @[@1, @4, @3, @5]
NSArray *results = ...; // result of fetch request
NSArray *sorted = [results sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSUInteger idx1 = [userIds indexOfObject:[obj1 valueForKey:@"userId"]];
    NSUInteger idx2 = [userIds indexOfObject:[obj2 valueForKey:@"userId"]];
    return idx1 - idx2;
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried your solution but can't quite get it to work. See my updated answer. Any ideas?

Comment: @Anders: Have you used the sort descriptor in the fetch request? You cannot do that! It is *not possible* to use such a sort descriptor in a fetch request. You have to fetch the results first, and then sort them as described in my answer. - Also I do not know why you use a transformable property, that will make things more complicated.

Comment: @MartinR Ok, do you know if it's possible to "resort" the result in a NSFechResultController fetch? I use a NSFechResultController as my datasource in the tableview...

Comment: @Anders: No, you can't reorder the "fetchedObjects" of the FRC. - What you theoretically could do is to "map" between table view rows and FRC rows in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. But then the FRC delegate methods `didChangeObject:...` must also be modified, so this is going to be complicated (and it is just an idea!). - If you really need a custom sort order that cannot be accomplished with a built-in sortdescriptor then it is probably better to remove the FRC. Just fetch the results into an array and sort them. If anything changes, reload the table view.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, will try the array route.

Comment: I have now trie you method. Like this: `self.objects = [self.objects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
            NSUInteger idx1 = [self.user.followingIds indexOfObject:[obj1 valueForKey:@"userId"]];
            NSUInteger idx2 = [self.user.followingIds indexOfObject:[obj2 valueForKey:@"userId"]];
            return idx1 - idx2;
        }]; ` But it doesn't seem to return the items in the right order. Do the types in `self.user.followingIds` and the value of `[obj1 valueForKey:@"userId"]` be `NSUInteger`'s?

Comment: @Anders: `self.user.followingIds` should be an NSArray or NSSet of NSNumber's, and `[obj1 valueForKey:@"userId"]` should also be a NSNumber.

Comment: @Anders: It seems to me that the whole problem can be extremly simplified if you replace `followingIds`  (which is probably an array of numbers) by a to-many *ordered relationship* `followers` (from User to User). Then `self.user.followers` is an NSOrderedSet of User objects and you don't have to sort at all. - It is just an idea, but perhaps you can use it!

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, thats a good idea! The only thing is that the user objects can be created in different locations/times. But that maybe wont matter? Could it work if I only add users to the Followers relationship when I actually needs to? Could I go back to the FRC? If so, how should the sort predicate look like?

Comment: @MartinR I added an update to my original post, is that relationship correct?

Comment: @Anders: You probably need one (ordered) relationship "followers" with another inverse relationship "following" or so. And this will also not work with an FRC. A FRC can only sort by (persistent) attributes. The advantage will only be that you don't have to sort the followers. - But this discussion is now moving away from your original question. May I suggest that you start a fresh question if you have problems with ordered relationships? Then other people have also the chance to reply to that problem.

Comment: @MartinR thanks Martin. I have created another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528039/predicate-for-many-to-many-relationship. If you want, then you can take a look. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

As @MartinR said, you cannot do that with sort descriptors.
 
To achieve a scalable solution in O(N) complexity (if you really need it):

```
//Not tested
NSArray* permutation = ...;//@[@1,@4,@3,@5] (user ids);
NSMutableDictionary* map = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[permutation count]];
for (NSUInteger i =0; i< [permutation count]; ++i) {
    map[permutation[i]] = @(i);
}
NSMutableArray* results = ...;//A mutable copy of the results
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [permutation count];) {
    id userId = [results[i] valueForKey:@"userId"];
    NSUInteger key = [map[userId] unsignedIntegerValue];//where we like this object to be
    if (key != i) {
        [results exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:key];
    } else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

**Analysis: (Please correct me if you spot any mistakes)**

The mapping stage takes N operation to complete: O(N)
The array copy takes N operations: O(N)
The loop iterate N times, but:
     it perform at max N exchanges
  and at max N comparisons
hence: O(N) + O(N) + O(N) + O(N) = 4*O(N) = O(N)

@MartinR solution will be based on a comparison based sort limited to a minimum O(N*lg(N)) operations.
however each comparison takes O(N) to get the first index and O(N) to get the second index.
hence: O(N*lg(N))*(O(N) + O(N)) = 2*O(N)*O(N*lg(N)) = O((N^2)*lg(N))

For small enough N there is no real difference (N=10 ==> ~40 operations for my solution and ~200 operations for Martin's solution).
For large N Martin's solutions will not scale well:
N == 1000 ==> ~4000 operations for my solution and ~2*1000*1000*8 =~ 16*10^6

Comment: The `while (key != i) { ... }` loop looks suspicious to me, because neither `key` nor `i` is modified in the loop body.

Comment: It should now progress as expected

Comment: Thanks, is the performance of this solution better then @MartinR's? And how/why is that?

Comment: That looks good now! And you are of course right that my solution does not scale well. Another O(N) solution would be to create a mapping from userId to the corresponding object (`NSDictionary *map = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:results forKeys:[results valueForKey:@"userId"]]`) - then you can build the sorted array with a simple loop. - But it seems to me that storing and sorting userIds instead of a proper (ordered) relationship is perhaps not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use this idea which i use to sort message id if it is added to DB

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"message_id" ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults=NO;
 NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Comment: Thanks, how do your localizedStandardCompare method look?

Comment: It compares strings with each other.Is it solved your problem

Comment: it is defined in header file NSString.h. it looks like /* localizedStandardCompare:, added in 10.6, should be used whenever file names or other strings are presented in lists and tables where Finder-like sorting is appropriate.  The exact behavior of this method may be tweaked in future releases, and will be different under different localizations, so clients should not depend on the exact sorting order of the strings.
*/
- (NSComparisonResult)localizedStandardCompare:(NSString *)string NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);

Comment: Simple solution is that when you are inserting userId into DB then please insert it according userIdArray then when you get to retrive it automatically comes as you have stored sorted.